# dagger2 in android can't inject Fragment with @FragmentKey

Tags: dagger-2

on dagger2 home page, it suggest use the annotation @FragmentKey to inject Fragment. But this Fragment is under the package android.app , but we usually use the Fragment that was under the package android.support.v4.app, so, how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

The `dagger.android.support` library is designed for this. See [the user guide (under "Android" -> "Support Libraries")](https://google.github.io/dagger/android.html#support-libraries), [the javadoc](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/android/support/package-summary.html), and [the code](https://github.com/google/dagger/tree/master/java/dagger/android/support).

Comment: Thanks! I did not notice that, it helps a lot.